# How to return to app after share / receive call / open external application in Android

Tags: android

I have a problem in Android Studio Project, 3 questions in one:

1. I click on share in menu and open options to share in: email, WhatsApp, etc. It works fine. But I need to know why my app is getting closed automatically after sharing?
2. If I receive a call when my app is open, when I terminate the call I go to Desktop and not to my last app Activity.
3. If I open another app from the Android Status bar, then when I click on back button or close second app, thus, it returns to desktop and not to my app.

Comment: Your application may be closing because it is using a large amount of memory and therefore the Android OS kills it off to make room for other processes.

Comment: i dunno, my aplication is a Basic WebView, with 4 itens in menu and all pages are webview.... I run an app named: Smart Truco its consume large ammount of memory, but when i receive call and terminate its come back at the same page.